# Python to detect point in polygons

Tags: python, point-in-polygon

First I import a shapefile

```
import geopandas as gpd
shapefile_path = "data/TRI_75_SIG_DI/TRI_PARI_SIG_DI/n_tri_pari_carte_inond_s_075.shp"
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
```

And it works fine.

[image]

Then I can display the polygons :

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[48.8566, 2.3522], zoom_start=12)
folium.GeoJson(gdf).add_to(m)
m
```

And it also works

[image]

Now, I choose a point, and we can see that it is in the polygons:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

point_coordinates = (2.3546, 48.8517) 
point = Point(point_coordinates)
m = folium.Map(location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]], zoom_start=13)
folium.Marker(
    location=[point_coordinates[1], point_coordinates[0]],
    icon=folium.Icon(color='blue'),
    popup="Point d'intérêt"
).add_to(m)
m
```

[image]

And I used the following code, that does not work because the result is empty, whereas there should be some polygons that contain this point:

```
gdf.geometry.contains(point)
```

Could you please help?

Comment: "That does not work" is not very helpful.  What does happen?

Comment: Did you notice the values in the `geometry` column?  They're in the 655,000 range.  They don't appear to be straight lat/long values.  There must be some kind of coordinate transformation needed.